# How do I print out to a .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, printing, text-mining

For my code below i was wanting to print out a full sentences in which certain words from my word lists appear, aswell it would print out the word count underneath each specific word into a .txt file. I succesfully achieved this in the terminal but am really struggling to get it into a .txt. At the moment i can only seem to get it to print out the word count in the .txt but the sentences are still printing to terminal, does anybody know where i maybe going wrong? Sorry for my lack of knowledge beginner learning python. Thanks

```
import re, os

pathWordLists = "E:\\Python\WordLists"

searchfilesLists = os.listdir(pathWordLists)

pathWordbooks = "E:\\Python\Books"

searchfilesbooks = os.listdir(pathWordBooks)

lush = open("WorkWork.txt", "w")


def searchDocs(word):

    for document in searchfilesbooks:
        file = os.path.join(pathWordbooks, document)
        text = open(file, "r")
        hit_count = 0
        for line in text:
            if re.findall(word, line):
                hit_count = hit_count +1
                print(document + " |" + line, end="")
        print(document + " => " + word + "=> "+ str(hit_count), file=lush)
        text.close()
    lush.flush()
    return

def searchWord():

    for document in searchfilesLists:
        file = os.path.join(pathWordLists, document)
        text = open(file, "r")
        for line in text:
            #print(line)
            searchDocs(line.strip())
        text.close()
    print("Finish")

searchWord()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're printing sentences with `print(document + " |" + line, end="")` you forgot the `file` parameter. Adding it should fix the problem:

```
print(document + " |" + line, end="", file=lush)
```

Comment: I've added it to both

print(document + " |" + line, end="", file=lush)

and 

print(document + " => " + word + "=> "+ str(hit_count), file=lush)

It now perfectly prints them both into the .txt but for some reason it says 'New Text Document.txt =>' is there anyway to get around this.

Thankyou so much for the help

Comment: For answering that I'd need to know the content of the directories you're scanning and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the result in a variable and then writing the variable to the file. Something like this:

```
def searchDocs(word):
    results = []
    for document in searchfilesbooks:
        file = os.path.join(pathWordbooks, document)
        with open(file, "r") as text:
            lines = text.readlines()

        hit_count = 0
        for line in lines:
            if re.findall(word, line):
                hit_count += 1
                results.append(document + " |" + line)
        results.append(document + " => " + word + "=> "+ str(hit_count))

    with open("WorkWork.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(results))
```